# Изменение данных в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть исходный DF , нужно создать столбец суммы C но на 1 ячейку вверх сдвинутый

Что есть:

```
    YEAR     A   B
0   2005    70  50
1   2006    80  60
2   2007    90  40
3   2008    100 80
4   2009    60  40
5   2010    50  60
6   2011    80  40
7   2012    70  66
```

Что нужно получить:

```
    YEAR     A   B    С
0                   120
1   2005    70  50  140
2   2006    80  60  130
3   2007    90  40  180
4   2008    100 80  100
5   2009    60  40  110
6   2010    50  60  120
7   2011    80  40  136
8   2012    70  66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = (pd.DataFrame([[pd.np.nan] * df.shape[1]], columns=df.columns)
         .append(df).reset_index(drop=True))

res['C'] = df.eval("A + B")
```

Результат:

```
In [168]: res
Out[168]:
      YEAR       A      B       C
0      nan     nan    nan 120.000
1 2005.000  70.000 50.000 140.000
2 2006.000  80.000 60.000 130.000
3 2007.000  90.000 40.000 180.000
4 2008.000 100.000 80.000 100.000
5 2009.000  60.000 40.000 110.000
6 2010.000  50.000 60.000 120.000
7 2011.000  80.000 40.000 136.000
8 2012.000  70.000 66.000     nan
```